Calendar view can't find multiple field settings
I have create a D10 (now in 10.2.6) site for booking PC in a internet cafè, I use calendar view module in 2.1 version.
when i insert the view of booking calendar there show me one calendar for every booking i add, i want to merge all of it in a single calendar.
I have read on the documentation the solution but I can't find it on my site, should I check the box  "Display all values in the same row" in Configure field:Content:Mycontentdate - Multiple field settings
but i don't have Multiple field settings in my view option.
there are the view configuration and the result whitout the content in the calendar.
thank you to everyone who will waste time for me.




Diego.
